# Core Graphics : Draw circle with intractable segments

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I managed to draw this circle with segments using core graphics. [image]

The circle is drawn using `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` and I added lines on top of it using `CGContextStrokePath`.

1. Is it possible to add interactivity to this circle segments to identify which segment area was touched by the user?
2. How Can I change the behaviour of each segments in the circle, for example Color, image & title for each segments?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the centre of the circle and you know the touch position it is fairly easy to calculate the angle that the touch is at.

Then it's just a case of separating the angles into different sections and reacting to the touch accordingly.